# Does the standard argument behind Bertrand's Postulate show that $\pi(2x)-\pi(x) > \frac{2n\log 2}{3\log 2n} -\sqrt{2n} - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The [standard argument](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/nt/cheb.pdf) for Bertrand's Postulate gives:

$$\left(\prod\limits_{2n \ge p > n} p\right)\left(2^{\frac{4n}{3}}\right)\left((2n)^{\sqrt{2n}}\right) > { {2n} \choose {n} } = \left(\prod\limits_{2n \ge p > n} p\right)\left(\prod\limits_{n \ge p > \sqrt{2n}} p\right)\left(\prod\limits_{\sqrt{2n} \ge p} p^{v_p(N)}\right) > \dfrac{2^{2n}}{2n}$$

So that:

$$\prod\limits_{2n \ge p > n} p > \dfrac{2^{\frac{2n}{3}}}{(2n)^{\sqrt{2n}+1}}$$

Since:

$$\log 2n\left[\pi(2n) - \pi(n)\right] > \prod\limits_{2n \ge p > n} \log p$$

Then:

$$\pi(2n) - \pi(n) > \frac{\frac{2n}{3}\log 2 - (\sqrt{2n}+1)\log (2n)}{\log 2n} = \frac{2n\log 2}{3\log 2n} -\sqrt{2n} - 1$$

Is my reasoning correct?

Thanks,

-Larry

---

Edit: Wanted to make my derivation of the first equation more clear.  Added details.

Comment: That first inequality doesn't occur anywhere in that paper, as far as I can see. Can you say how you deduced that?

Comment: It is from Page 80.  The proof assumes that $\prod\limits_{2n \ge p > n}$ is $1$ and finds a contradiction in the assumption that $(2n)^{\sqrt{2n}}2^{4n/3} \ge \frac{2^{2n}}{2n}$.

Comment: No, that product is $\prod_{\nu_p=1}$, not what you've written. I'm not clear where the $\Theta(2n/3)$ cane from, however. Is that supposed to be the upper bound for $$\prod_{\sqrt{2n}<p\leq n} p,$$ and, if so, is that upper bound really true if there are primes in $(n,2n)$?

Comment: @Thomas, if we assume that there are no primes between $2n$ and $n$ then $\prod\limits_{2n \ge p > n} p = 1$.  So, I'm not clear why you say "no".  The standard argument is to show that for each $p > \frac{2n}{3}$, $v_p(N) = 0$ so that $\prod\limits_{\sqrt{2n} \le p < n} p < 2^{4n/3}$  This comes from the standard argument that $\prod\limits_{p \le x} < 4^x$ and to show that for $\sqrt{2n} \le p < \frac{2n}{3}$, $v_p(N)=1$.  Perhaps, I am misunderstanding your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds correct. Interestingly, the prime number theorem implies that
$$\pi(2n)-\pi(n) \sim \frac{n}{\ln n},$$
and the above lower bound $\frac{2n\ln 2}{3\ln 2n}$ has the same order of magnitude (up to positive [smaller] constant, but well, that's already a lot..) :)